# WPF form in VSTO Outlook Add-In - data entry issues

Tags: wpf, outlook, vsto, add-in

I have a VSTO (.net 4) Outlook Add-In which opens a WPF form.

There are a number of controls on the form, including 2 textboxes.

If I open the form when I have an email selected (with focus) in the Email Explorer then everything works as expected.

However...

If I open the form when I have given any email focus by clicking on the email body (ie the message itself) then the textboxes on my form won't accept the space key or key combinations such as Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V.
If, for example, hitting Space then Outlook (in the background) cycles to the next email.

It turns out this is a known issue but I thought for a workaround I could set the Email Explorer to have focus just before I open the form.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

***Solution***

OK, thanks to SliverNinja I've managed this workaround which does make the selected email in the preview pane disappear and then reappear but it works which is good enough for me...

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var activeExplorer = app.ActiveExplorer();

var previewPaneVisibility = activeExplorer.IsPaneVisible(OlPane.olPreview);
activeExplorer.ShowPane(OlPane.olPreview, false);
activeExplorer.ShowPane(OlPane.olPreview, previewPaneVisibility);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't verified, but here are some ideas for you...

You could try resetting the `ActiveExplorer().Selection` to change focus. If you are using Outlook 2010, you have access to [`Explorer.ClearSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862680.aspx) and [`Explorer.AddToSelection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868732.aspx). [`Explorer.Activate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865063.aspx) may also change the focus - I don't have 2010 to check though.

Another option to consider is hiding the Message Preview Pane or toggling it. See [`Explorer.ShowPane`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff863893.aspx) and [`Explorer.IsPaneVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869316.aspx).

The only other possible solution to this would be to go outside the boundaries of the VSTO COM wrappers and dig into the lower level interfaces. Checkout [`IDTExtensibility2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for lower-level behaviors.

Comment: Hi SliverNinja,  Thanks for the suggestions - I'll try them out and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks SliverNinja, I managed to force a defocus of the preview pane.  I've updated the question with the solution your suggestions provided.

Comment: Nicely done @Drammy! Thanks for posting back the solution for us.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but we had this issue also and solved it by opening such WPF windows on a new thread.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that sounds like a good idea - I will try that next time I develop another VSTO addin - cheers! (not sure who's marked your answer down or why!? .. so I've marked you back up)

Comment: Thanks, Drammy! I don't know why, either, but as that was my first post in this forum I didn't want to ask :)